# Extjs Store shows zero records just after application refresh

Tags: mysql, extjs, store, extjs4.2

As I invoke a function from controller that performs the following task,

```
var store= new Ext.getStore('MyStore'); //The store gets its data from mysql db
store.load(); 
console.log(store.getTotalCount());
```

shows the total count as zero for the 1st time after application refresh and shows the actual count i.e the actual number of rows in the store for subsequent invocation of the function.

I would really appreciate if someone could please guide me towards the resolution of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `store.load()` is asynchronous (I assume that you use remote proxy like ajax) and you call `store.getTotalCount()` immediately after you call `store.load()` first time you use it store is not loaded yet.

You have to check totalCount withink store load callback, like this:

```
var store= Ext.getStore('MyStore'); //The store gets its data from mysql db
store.load({
    callback: function() {
        console.log(store.getTotalCount());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var store= new Ext.getStore('MyStore'); //The store gets its data from mysql db
store.load(); 
console.log(store.getTotalCount());
```

I am not sure whether you should use the new keyword on first line. A store is referenced like this -

var store = Ext.getStore('MyStore');

Also, please make sure, your service is returning total count, that is very unlikely though since you said you can see proper count on subsequent calls. Just try removing the new keyword and let me know.

Comment: thank you so much 4 ur response,
 the code works fine with 'new' keyword.

Comment: If the new keyword is not an issue then  it could be an issue with the store proxy or your service response. Can you please provide the store code and the service response that you are getting?

Comment: You should still take out the `new` keyword, it's just a waste and you shouldn't use it with Ext.getStore